# Empty space in BarChartGraph using GraphView library

Tags: android, android-layout, view, graph, charts

I am currently trying to draw a graph using GraphView library (http://www.jjoe64.com/p/graphview-library.html). I am currently using version 3.

I've a problem about Bar in BarChartGraph. I push a 33-elements array but char are smaller of the entire graph, in the graph remain a no used space.

I attached an image.

This is the XML code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/txtX" 
        android:text="X: 0" 
        android:textSize="15sp"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtZ"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="Z: 0"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
    [....]

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:focusable="false">
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/graph1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this the code about graph in the main class:

```
  GraphViewData[] data;
    GraphView graphView;

     // Inizializzazioni utili per il grafico  
        data = new GraphViewData[(N/2)+1];  // N=64

        graphView = new BarGraphView(this, "example") {  //Prova a mettere primad di questo setHorizontalabe
            @Override
            protected String formatLabel(double value, boolean isValueX) {
                if (isValueX) {
                    return Double.toString(value);
                } else return super.formatLabel(value, isValueX); // let the y-value be normal-formatted
               }
            };

      LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph1);   
      layout.addView(graphView);

        for (int i=0; i<(N/2)+1; i++)
           data[i] = new GraphViewData(i, new_sig[i]);

      graphView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

      graphView.addSeries(new GraphViewSeries(data));

      graphView.invalidate();
      graphView.redrawAll();
```

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5sm5aNTZkIiN1hrV1Q2MU9iYmM

I set:

```
graphView.setViewPort(0, 33);
```

But nothing changed!

I tried also with a smaller ViewPort but the result was the same, like the image in this new post. 
In this case the ViewPort was 20:

```
graphView.setViewPort(0, 20);
```

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5sm5aNTZkIiMFlSSFd1T1ViQ00

But how show in the figure, remain the empty space!

I tried also to change in XML file the dimension tags.
I swaped "wrap_content" to "match_parent", but no result.
Then i was changing to match_parent also the partent view LinearLayout, and then also the ScrollView.

I tried also creating a series of 8 data (data.length=8), but the result was the same, reamin the same empty space at the right of the graph.

Thank's for all! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have already solved that, but it can help somebody else.
I had the same issue. I found the solution here. [BarGraphView · Issue #14 · jjoe64/GraphView · GitHub](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/issues/14)

You have to modify the source code of the library like this:

```
// BarGraphView.java
// float colwidth = (graphwidth - (2 * border)) / values.length;
float colwidth = graphwidth / values.length;

// GraphView.java
// horizontal labels + lines
int hors = horlabels.length;
for (int i = 0; i <= horlabels.length; i++) {
    paint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    float x = ((graphwidth / hors) * i) + horstart;
    canvas.drawLine(x, height - border, x, border, paint);
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    if (i < horlabels.length) {
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawText(horlabels[i], x + (graphwidth / hors) / 2,
                height - 4, paint);
    }
}
```

It worked for me very well. I hope it helps.